# django-post_office - Using file-based instead of database-based email templates

Tags: python, django

I'm using [django-post_office](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office) to send emails to users. Post office uses templates stored in the database in the `EmailTemplate` model. I'd prefer to use file-based templates so I can keep them under version control.

An `Email` is created and the template is rendered in mail.py:

```
def create(sender, recipients=None, cc=None, bcc=None, subject='', message='',
           html_message='', context=None, scheduled_time=None, headers=None,
           template=None, priority=None, render_on_delivery=False,
           commit=True):
    ...
    if template:
        subject = template.subject
        message = template.content
        html_message = template.html_content

    if context:
        _context = Context(context)
        subject = Template(subject).render(_context)
        message = Template(message).render(_context)
        html_message = Template(html_message).render(_context)
```

Can anyone suggest a nice way to override this behavior? I was thinking I'd like to be able to pass a string with the template location, and render based on this (some context variables), but any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to render the email template before calling `mail.send()` along with any extra context variables.

```
from django.template import Context, loader
template = loader.get_template(template_name)
context = Context(extra_context)
html_message = template.render(context)
```

Then instead of passing a template:

```
mail.send(template=template)
```

pass rendered html with the html_message argument:

```
mail.send(html_message=html_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is very simple, as when we see the code which creates and sends an email, I see that the [`mail.send(...)`](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office/blob/30a4eb9e96ee4a5a495574ab615c83c6999d20d4/post_office/mail.py#L93) calls internally [`mail.create(...)`](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office/blob/30a4eb9e96ee4a5a495574ab615c83c6999d20d4/post_office/mail.py#L141)

Now here is that code:

```
def send(recipients=None, sender=None, template=None, context=None, subject='',
         message='', html_message='', scheduled_time=None, headers=None,
         priority=None, attachments=None, render_on_delivery=False,
         log_level=None, commit=True, cc=None, bcc=None):
     
    #-------------
    #code sections
    #-------------

    if template:
        if subject:
            raise ValueError('You can\'t specify both "template" and "subject" arguments')
        if message:
            raise ValueError('You can\'t specify both "template" and "message" arguments')
        if html_message:
            raise ValueError('You can\'t specify both "template" and "html_message" arguments')

        # template can be an EmailTemplate instance or name
        if isinstance(template, EmailTemplate):
            template = template
        else:
            template = get_email_template(template)

    email = create(sender, recipients, cc, bcc, subject, message, html_message,
                   context, scheduled_time, headers, template, priority,
                   render_on_delivery, commit=commit)
```

The interesting piece of code is:

```
# template can be an EmailTemplate instance or name
            if isinstance(template, EmailTemplate):
                template = template
            else:
                template = get_email_template(template)
```

The [`get_email_template`](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office/blob/65abe6e3de114084e03782f1ff27fe4a517f7dcb/post_office/utils.py#L82) gets the template using either the `EmailTemplate` or `name` of the `EmailTemplate` which is during cache creation.

Even if you do not pass the object of `EmailTemplate` (in their case the model), they have just two cases:

1. Either get the data from the cache (which is again stored for first access from DB, since template wont change)
2. Get directly from DB

Either way they use DB and have no interface for using from a file.

**I would suggest something like this:**

1. Create a json file that stores your template in the format that suffices the `EmailTemplate` object creation. Here are the properties of `EmailTemplate` model class:

   `name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text=("e.g: 'welcome_email'"))
   description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Description of this template.')
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, validators=[validate_template_syntax])
   content = models.TextField(blank=True, validators=[validate_template_syntax])
   html_content = models.TextField(blank=True, validators=[validate_template_syntax])
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`
2. Read that json file in python using file read and convert the read string to python object by json dump or something (i guess you can figure that out)
3. Create the `EmailTemplate` object using the value you need and assign it to `template` in `mail.send(...`

**Update:**
If you use `html_message`, you still have maintain separate `subject` parameter, which can be avoided if you use `template`. So if you use json file, in your version control, from the `subject`,`content`,`name` and `html_message` everything will be stored in one file which can be handled in the file source control and recreate the template object and not worry about segregated values in the files to maintain.

Comment: Creating `EmailTemplate` objects would work well with your solution. If this behavior was not required, however, an easier solution could be to render HTML beforehand, as mentioned in my answer. Ideally, I don't want to have to read a JSON file and create / update all `EmailTemplate` objects every time I make a change to a template.

Comment: Okay :) I understand, but since you wanted some way to get the template to source control, I thought you can create the json file that holds your details in a file and then read the file and create the `EmailTemplate` object.

Comment: Also, if you specify `mail.send(html_message)` you will miss out the `subject` and `content` which is provided by `template` and not by `html_message`. This [**code**](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office/blob/30a4eb9e96ee4a5a495574ab615c83c6999d20d4/post_office/mail.py#L64) will explain that you will loose out `subject`. So I suggest ensure you create an entire `email template` and not just have `html_message`.

Comment: You can also specify these fields when calling `mail.send(subject=subject, message=message)`. `EmailTemplate.content` is simply rendered and set as `message`: [link](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office/blob/30a4eb9e96ee4a5a495574ab615c83c6999d20d4/post_office/models.py#L75), but yes, it is true that you will not get that automatically without creating an `EmailTemplate`. I would up-vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. :) But I still believe if you can think of single `template` object and not pass multiple values for `subject` and `html_message`, you can have entire thing under object to monitor for your source controlled file. Anyways, its about perception. :) [P.S.: I din't know with less reputation you cannot upvote :D]